# css font-size inheritance not applying

Tags: html, css

I have a structure like follows

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="title">My little pony</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the title div has its font-size set, but so does the panel div.

```
.panel {
    font-size: 0.89em;
}
.product .title {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 3.8em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

When I look at this in the browser it appears that the font-size for the panel class is applying to the title div, firebug does show the panel style as being crossed out but when toggling the font-size on the title div it makes no difference to the size.

If I toggle the panel class font-size then I can see that change that I am expecting.

What is going on here am I missing something obvious?

Note: css has been simplified

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnjEL/)

Comment: This works for me in FFx and Chrome, both current.  Are you targeting a particular browser? http://jsfiddle.net/qQW37/

Comment: jsve has it below, when its 1 its related to the parent container so setting it bigger than one works

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance. You should explain what you want, show how you tried that, and say what is wrong with the result. Now the question does not even specify what the goal is.

Comment: Well I did not know the issue was not inheritance, so to best of my knowledge I have asked the question, I did show what I already had, what I had tried (working with firebug). I will give you that the goal could have been clearer though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `font-size` is being overridden (that's why you see it crossed out in Firebug), but it doesn't actually do anything because of the relativity of `em`s.

`1em` = the font size of the parent element. In your case, this is `.panel` with `font-size: 0.89em`. So setting `.product .title`'s `font-size` to `1em` doesn't affect the outcome.

---

**Formula to calculate em equivalent for any pixel value required**

```
1 ÷ parent font size (px) × required pixels = em equivalent
```

*(Credit: http://v1.jontangerine.com/silo/css/pixels-to-ems/)*

Per this formula, to get the desired font size you need to set it to:

```
1.1235955056179775280898876404494
```

*Note: the browser can't render an umteenzillionth of a pixel so only a few decimal places are actually needed.*

Comment: So is it possible to get the font-size to appear as it would if the outer font-size wasnt applied, without actually removing the outer font-size. Trying to see if I can get away without changing some css, but I'm guessing it wont work.

Comment: If my math is correct I think I need to set it to about 1.12em

Comment: @DanielPowell Yes. See my edit for the (almost) exact value you need to set it to.